# How to see GWT devmode from another machine using External Public IP

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, ip, jetty

I have followed by adding argument -bindAddress 0.0.0.0 which works fine and binds to my private IP with the URL:

```
http://192.168.0.103:8888/StockWatcher.html
```

The arguments in Run Configurations are:

```
-superDevMode -startupUrl StockWatcher.html -logLevel INFO -port 8888 -bindAddress 0.0.0.0 -war C:\Users\Vampire\workspace\StockWatcher\war -server com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher -remoteUI
```

I can see the website running on my mobile device too with it. I want to bind it to my external Public IP so that anyone can see having my Public IP not on the same router like as private IP but globally with my Public IP Address. Please help me how to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup port forwarding from your router to your local computer.
Target IP will be your local IP `192.168.0.103` and target port is `8888`.

A guide like [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/) one might help you. Or just have a look into your routers manual.

*Just note:*
If you are using Super Dev Mode, you might have to think about security like stated [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html):

> The code server has no authentication. It also serves all your Java source code to any user who asks. Therefore, we recommend only running it on localhost or behind a firewall. (It uses localhost by default.)